# How to Update Statistics on a single column in a table?

Tags: sql, statistics, sql-update

I'm currently doing an investigation to determine the update statistic duration for tables of different sizes (100K, 1M, 10M, 100M, etc rows) with a table that has one column.

Currently I have tables created with the correct row sizes, however they do not have one column, rather 5, 6, 7 etc.

I was wondering whether there was a way to update a certain column in a table or a certain number of columns in a table.

Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using a database that I have created

Comment: What I meant was, which database *software* are you using?

Comment: Sorry I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: How about creating a table with one column which consists of all the columns in your other table concatenated together?

Answer (score 0):

You can update certain column's statistics by specifying that column's name in a query:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [my_schema].[my_table] [my_column] WITH FULLSCAN;
```